# loadFromWaypoints with more than 25 points using Google Maps API v2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gdirections

I have a problem. I know that in google maps, the `GDirections.loadFromWayPoints` has limit of 25 `GLatLng` objects. What I want is to make a route of, say, 300 points.

How can I do that? The solution I thought of was using arrays of 25 positions, and then call loadFromWaypoints, create another array of 25 positions, and call loadFromWayPoints and so on, but when I do this, I can just see the first array in my map.

Any suggestions?

Here is my ajax function which attempts to do what I've described:

```
function ajaxFunction(url){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

        var dirMap = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

           var cnt = 0;
           var cen = 0;
           var rta = ajaxRequest.responseText.split("^");

           for (var i = 0; i<(rta.length) -1; i++)

           {

            var reg = rta[i].split("$");
            var lat = reg[0];
            var lng = reg[1];

            if (cnt == 24) {

                var marker = new GMarker(arrayWP[1]);
                dirMap.addOverlay(marker);
                if (cen == 0) {
                   dirMap.setCenter(arrayWP[0], 12);
                   cen = 1;
                }
                dirMap.setUIToDefault();

                directions = new GDirections(dirMap);
                directions.loadFromWaypoints(arrayWP);
                arrayWP[0] = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
                cnt = 1;

            }
            else
            {
                arrayWP[cnt] = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
                cnt++;
            }

           }

         /*  if (cen == 0) {
                var marker = new GMarker(arrayWP[1]);
                dirMap.addOverlay(marker);
                if (cen == 0) {
                   dirMap.setCenter(arrayWP[0], 12);
                   cen = 1;
                }
                dirMap.setUIToDefault();

                directions = new GDirections(dirMap);
                directions.loadFromWaypoints(arrayWP);
           }*/

        }     
    }                             

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

PathPolyline does the job: https://github.com/spinningcode/PathPolyline

From its description:

> PathPolyline is a simple library that can be used to get around the 25 points limitation on the maximum number of waypoints with GDirection.loadFromWaypoints method (Google Map API V2).

The [readme file](https://github.com/spinningcode/PathPolyline#readme) has some usage instructions and demonstration code which you may find helpful.

Comment: I've added some slight detail to your answer. Whilst the link alone you gave does answer the question, we encourage a little surrounding detail so that if the link ever goes dead, the answer is not entirely useless. Just something to bear in mind to help you out. Welcome to SO, by the way :)